# Working in ObjC, not in swift. Whats wrong I am doing with JSON parsing in swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, nsjsonserialization

I just wanted to Parse JSON from URL,
The code below written in ObjC is working well and giving me correct response,
but the code written in swift 3.1, not giving correct response.
Giving me `500 Internal Error`

Whats wrong I am doing.
Can anyone guide.
Thanks in advance.

I also tried to use converter from ObjC to Swift.
But it fails with some errors, though I solve those errors, but still not giving correct output.

ObjC code below.

```
-(void)comparedatainserturl

{
    NSError *error;
    NSMutableArray *arr=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    NSMutableDictionary *dict=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];

    [dict setObject:@"e639e129d0f3ab7d" forKey:@"imei_no"];
    [dict setObject:@"2017-08-29 12:18:44" forKey:@"current_time"];
    [dict setObject:@"0" forKey:@"tbl_offer_details"];
    [dict setObject:@"0" forKey:@"tbl_card_type"];
    [dict setObject:@"0" forKey:@"tbl_dashboard"];
    [dict setObject:@"0" forKey:@"tbl_category_details"];
    [dict setObject:@"0" forKey:@"tbl_sub_category_details"];
    [dict setObject:@"0" forKey:@"tbl_payment_option"];
    [dict setObject:@"0" forKey:@"tbl_payment_option_provider"];
    [dict setObject:@"0" forKey:@"tbl_like_favorite_share"];
    [dict setObject:@"0" forKey:@"tbl_user_details"];

    [arr addObject:dict];

    NSLog(@"arra :- %@",[arr description]);

    NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:arr options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error];
    NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"data=%@",jsonString];

    NSLog(@"jsonData as string:\n%@", string);

    NSData *data = [string dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSString *urlString=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",@"http://admin.scontos.com/index.php/Android_api/Offers_download"];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    [request setHTTPMethod: @"POST"];

    [request setHTTPBody: data];

    NSError *err;

    NSURLResponse *response;

    NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&err];

    NSString *resSrt = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:responseData encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

    NSLog(@"gotresponsestring=%@", resSrt);
}
```

Swift Code below,

```
func  comparedatainserturl() {


        var arrayParams : NSDictionary = [:]

        arrayParams  = ["imei_no":"e639e129d0f3ab7d","current_time":"2017-08-2911:08:26","tbl_offer_details":"0","tbl_card_type":"0","tbl_dashboard":"0","tbl_category_details":"0","tbl_sub_category_details":"0","tbl_payment_option":"0","tbl_payment_option_provider":"0","tbl_like_favorite_share":"0","tbl_user_details":"0"]

        print(arrayParams)

        let valueArr : Array = [arrayParams]
        print(valueArr)

        let jsonData: Data? = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: valueArr, options: .prettyPrinted)

        let jsonString = String(data: jsonData!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
        let string: String = "data=\(jsonString)"
        print("jsonData as string:\n\(string)")
        let dataa: Data? = string.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)

        var _: NSError?
        let url1:URL = URL(string:"http://admin.scontos.com/index.php/Android_api/Offers_download")!
        let request:NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url1)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"

        request.httpBody = dataa

        var response: URLResponse?

        do{
            let urlData: Data? = try NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request as URLRequest, returning:&response)


            let resstr = NSString(data: urlData!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
            print("Response is \(resstr! as String)")

        }catch{
            print(error)
        }

    }
```

Comment: What basic debugging strategies have you tried?

Comment: BTW, I'd advise against using ObjC -> Swift converters, if possible. They generate literal translations, which results in very bad code. It's like expecting Google Translate to convert a poem in French into English. Sure, all the words will be there, but it will be horrible poem.

Comment: Is your url working? Because I am getting some database error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your swift code you are appending the following string.

`let jsonString = String(data: jsonData!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)`
/*In following line you are appending JsonString with optional value with optional key word with this "()". So you need to unwrap the optional value*/

`let string: String = "data=\(jsonString!)"`

Answer (score 0):

Your code is sending a body of a request that effectively looks like:

```
data=[
  {
    "key1" : "value1", 
    "key2" : "value2", ...
  }
]
```

That is incorrect.

- If your server was expecting just the JSON, you should send the JSON without the `data=` prefix.
- If your server is expecting a `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` request, then that value cannot have spaces, newline characters, or any other reserved characters in it. In this case, you have to "percent escape" the body of the request.

You should confirm precisely what the web service is expecting, and adjust your code accordingly.

---

Unrelated, I'd retire the `NS` classes and stay within Swift. So, assuming you wanted to just send JSON, the code might look like:

```
func comparedatainserturl() {
    let arrayParams = [
        [
            "imei_no":"e639e129d0f3ab7d",
            "current_time":"2017-08-2911:08:26",
            "tbl_offer_details":"0",
            "tbl_card_type":"0",
            "tbl_dashboard":"0",
            "tbl_category_details":"0",
            "tbl_sub_category_details":"0",
            "tbl_payment_option":"0",
            "tbl_payment_option_provider":"0",
            "tbl_like_favorite_share":"0",
            "tbl_user_details":"0"
        ]
    ]

    let data = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: arrayParams)

    let jsonString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!
    let string: String = "data=" + jsonString
    print("jsonData as string:\n\(string)")

    let url1 = URL(string:"http://admin.scontos.com/index.php/Android_api/Offers_download")!
    var request = URLRequest(url: url1)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"        
    request.httpBody = data

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
        if let error = error {
            print(error)
            return
        }

        guard let data = data else { return }

        let string = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
        print("response is \(string)")
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

Or, if the server was expecting `x-www-form-urlencoded` request:

```
let data = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: arrayParams)

let jsonString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!
let string: String = "data=" + jsonString.addingPercentEncodingForQuery()!

let url1 = URL(string:"http://admin.scontos.com/index.php/Android_api/Offers_download")!
var request = URLRequest(url: url1)
request.httpMethod = "POST"
request.httpBody = string.data(using: .utf8)
```

Where you percent escape using this routine, adapted from Alamofire's [`escape` routine](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Source/ParameterEncoding.swift#L195):

```
extension String {
    public func addingPercentEncodingForQuery() -> String? {
        let generalDelimitersToEncode = ":#[]@" // does not include "?" or "/" due to RFC 3986 - Section 3.4
        let subDelimitersToEncode = "!$&'()*+,;="

        var allowed = CharacterSet.urlQueryAllowed
        allowed.remove(charactersIn: generalDelimitersToEncode + subDelimitersToEncode)

        return addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: allowed)
    }
}
```